# How to quit serial-term?

Tags: term

I opened a serial-term to /dev/ttyUSB0. I can't quit it. `C-x k` results in the following message:

`term-quit-subjob: Process /dev/ttyUSB0 is not a subprocess`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to kill the buffer with `C-c k`.

General: all `C-x` keys should work, if you use `C-c` instead. So to change to another window would be `C-c o` instead of `C-x o`.

*Edit* `C-c <letter>` is often used for user keybindings, therefore you maybe might need to unbound your user keybinding before this works.

Comment: I stated in the question that this doesn't work. Perhaps it's a bug. I'll try it with `emacs -q` to test.

Comment: You only stated, that it is not working with `C-x k` this is different, becuase you should use `C-c k` instead. my solution is working on my setup (but I have to unbound my private setting of `C-c k` before)

Comment: `C-c k` runs `(kill-buffer)` in term's char mode, same as `C-x k` does in line mode. The output in the question is from kill-buffer. But since asking, I've updated my dot files and now it works. :¯\_(ツ)_/¯